# How to read keyboard input in real time with C?

Tags: c, keyboard, arm, fpga

I bought a DE1 SoC this summer and programmed a small CPU into the FPGA part. Back then, I had access to a PS2 keyboard that connected directly to the board, but now I don't and I need a way of communicating with the CPU. Luckily, the Cyclone V chip contains an ARM Cortex A9 that I can connect to the FPGA fabric and can run Linux distributions. The CPU in the FPGA part has a memory register which updates every clock cycle with the key scan code it used to read from the PS2 keyboard. My plan was to emulate this functionality by writing some code in C that would likewise read my keystrokes and send them over to the FPGA. This last part, I know how to do. It is the reading the keys part that confuses me. Ideally, I would like a function that, on execution, it read whatever input was coming from the keyboard, even if no keys are being pressed, without delay. I read some other questions on here that suggested things like getch() and getchar() and some other functions, but they all seem to require third party libraries and I am not sure these are supported by the compiler for the ARM processor.

It need not be necessarily C, it could be any other programming language that I could compile to run on the Cortex A9, it can even be assembly if it makes it more straightforward. All I need is to read whatever input is currently being sent by the keyboard, even if there is none. I can use a VNC to talk to the ARM chip over the local network or I can also connect to it via UART, whichever simplifies the process.

Comment: They are std libraries.  Try it out and see.  If not, then that is a good question.

Comment: Yes, the C standard library only deals with streams and is probably not suitable for what you want. One would have to write this themselves or use a third-party library.

Comment: Need a bit more information.  What compiler and toolchain are you using?  Is the Cortex-A9 running a full Linux distro?  How is the keyboard connected to the A9?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu with kernel 4.5 supplied here https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=205&No=836&PartNo=4. I am using a Linaro Mentor Graphics GCC based toolchain. When I compile I use the command arm-linux-gnueabihf but I also downloaded Eclipse DS 5 which has an Arm compiler 5 (but I think that is for baremetal applications). Finally, I am using tightvnc as a vnc server and RealVNC as a viewer, but I am willing to change any of these tools if convenient.